# how to create and extend reusable gitlab pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a pipeline like below:

```
include:
  - project: "some-project"
    ref: 0.5.0
    file: reusable-jobs.yml

variables:
  VAR1: ""

stages:
  - stage-1
  - stage-2

job1:
  extends: .reusable-job-1
  stage: stage-1
  variables:
    SOME_VAR: "$VAR1"

job2:
  extends: .reusable-job-2
  stage: stage-2
  variables:
    SOME_VAR: "$VAR1"
```

I want to be able to save this an imported into other projects. with my reusable jobs I create one like this

```
.some-reusable-job:
  image:
    name: alpine
  script:
    - echo "hello"
```

and then I extended it when I want to use it

ex:

```
reuse_the_job:
  extends: .some-reusable-job
  stage: some-stage
```

but I cannot figure out how to do the same thing with the entire pipeline including the stages

I want to be able to call the pipeline like so:

```
reuse_the_pipeline:
  extends: .my-reusable-pipeline
  variables:
    VAR1: "hello"
```

and have the pipeline be created with both stage_1 and stage_2

I tried to create a definition like this in `reusable-flow-file.yml`

```
.reusable-flow
    include:
      - project: "some-project"
        ref: 0.5.0
        file: reusable-jobs.yml
    
    variables:
      VAR1: ""
    
    stages:
      - stage-1
      - stage-2
    
    job1:
      extends: .reusable-job-1
      stage: stage-1
      variables:
        SOME_VAR: "$VAR1"
    
    job2:
      extends: .reusable-job-2
      stage: stage-2
      variables:
        SOME_VAR: "$VAR1"
```

and then use it like this (.gitlab-ci.yml)

```
include:
  - local: "reusable-flow-file.yml"


dev_na:
  extends: .reusable-flow
  variables:
    VAR1: "hello"
```

but when I try to run it and get lab I get this error

> config should implement a script: or a trigger: keyword

not really sure what that try

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're extending the ".reusable-flow" on a job-level. And what you're actually getting is (the following) which is invalid, because the job `dev_na` has no `script` property.

```yaml
dev_na:
    include:
      - project: "some-project"
        ref: 0.5.0
        file: reusable-jobs.yml
    
    variables:
      VAR1: ""
    
    stages:
      - stage-1
      - stage-2
    
    job1:
      extends: .reusable-job-1
      stage: stage-1
      variables:
        SOME_VAR: "$VAR1"
    
    job2:
      extends: .reusable-job-2
      stage: stage-2
      variables:
        SOME_VAR: "$VAR1"
    variables:
      VAR1: "hello"
```

---

You should just define the jobs (and other stuff) on the root level of your template. And play around a bit in the Project > CI/CD > editor where you can get a life preview of the templated configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the new [GitLab 16.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/05/22/gitlab-16-0-released/#cicd-components) (May 2023) helps with:

> ### CI/CD components
>
> In this release we are excited to announce the availability of CI/CD components, as an experimental feature.
>
> A CI/CD component is a reusable single-purpose building block that can be used to compose a part of a project’s CI/CD configuration, or even an entire pipeline.
>
> When combined with the [`inputs`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#define-inputs-for-configuration-added-with-include-beta) keyword, a CI/CD component can be made much more flexible.
> You can configure the component to your exact needs by inputting values which can be used for job names, variables, credentials, and so on.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/components/) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/9897).

---

And [GitLab 16.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/12/21/gitlab-16-7-released/#cicd-catalog-beta-release) (December 2023) adds:

> ### CI/CD Catalog - Beta release
>
> GitLab 16.7 sees the Beta release of the CI/CD catalog! The catalog is where you can search for [CI/CD components](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/components/) maintained by you, your organization, or the public community. This is the place where DevOps engineers come together to create, contribute, and share reusable pipeline configurations.
>
> Unlike other methods of reusing CI/CD configuration, CI/CD components published in the catalog have an improved experience, and are easily added to your pipeline. We invite you to start testing this new and exciting feature! You can try out components that others have created and shared in the catalog, or create your own components and share them with everyone.
>
> While this is our initial beta release of the feature, we continue to work on making the experience even better. Our goal is to make the CI/CD catalog a fundamental part of the GitLab CI/CD experience.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/components/#cicd-catalog) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/11674).